# How does Android Studio handle image sizes?

Tags: android, image, screen-size

I have an application where I use background images.

I don´t want my images to be stretched or deformed when I run my application on different screens with different ratios.

I already have different images for different screen sizes.

1. Can someone please explain to me how Android Studio handles the image sizes.
2. How can I make it that the image isn´t streched, but a sector that fits the screen is being displayed?

Comment: put images of different size in differenct `drawable-xxx` folder.

Comment: but I don´t know the users tablets or phones screenrelations

Comment: create different layout for different device.

Comment: @Rustam i did but my picture is not as wide as the screen of my testing tablet so it is being streched a little bit

Comment: you should put images  according to your device size.

Comment: but I don´t know what device

Comment: It does not handle at all. Android studio is an IDE

Answer (score 0):

Android System uses resource qualifiers/filters to load different resources based on current screen configuration.

Now you have different images for different screen sizes, Good!!

the Folder structure would be something like this.

res
  -drawable-mdpi
  -drawable-hdpi
  -drawable-xhdpi
  -drawable-xxhdpi

Now when you run your Application on a device with mdpi screen, android loads images which are under drawable-mdpi folder, and when you run your application on a device with screen density of xhdpi android loads images from drawable-xhdpi folder.

Comment: and this way the image isn´t deformed? do mdpi, hdpi... discribe the side relations?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the image as a background for my layout I created an image view. There I set the scale Type to centerCrop and it had the wanted effect!